# Run drupal website over only HTTPS

Tags: 6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simply make the whole site https](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https)

I have my drupal 6 website running on apache. I want this site to run only on HTTPS. What should be done for this. There are lot many solutions, which are getting me confused. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) and [Secure Pages Hijack Prevention](http://drupal.org/project/securepages_prevent_hijack) modules.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect using the `.htaccess` file in Drupal's root directory. It should already have a couple of *rewriting* examples that you can adapt. If not, please see [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D%20redirect%20https) on SE and elsewhere on the web.