# How to change base url protocol to HTTPS?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I wanted to update the protocol of my base url to HTTPS. I have added nginx configuration to redirect all http requests to https.
But in meta tag, when I choose [site:url], it returns a http url, http://www/example.com

How do I change the base url protocol in my website? 
I used a third party tool to analyze my site SEO performance. As per the report, there are http href links in my website like http://www.example.com/search, http://www.example.com/user. These are search menu and user profile pages. How do I fix it? How do I tell my drupal that my site's protocol is HTTPS and base url should be https://www.example.com ?

Comment: Have you flushed your site cache while on https? As everything has probably been cached as http:// previously

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known bug tracked on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2842049).

Comment: Also try out this one: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/268061/15055 but `str_replace` just the other way around.