# Make it so that ALL pages are served over SSL using .htaccess

Tags: redirection, .htaccess, ssl

I'm trying to make it so that ALL pages are served over SSL and have a https:// prefix.

I'm using the latest Drupal (as of 16.2.15) and running Apache (Fast CGI)

I'd really like it so that if a visitor were to type in:

```
http://example.com/test1
http://example.com/test2
```

they's end up at:

```
https://example.com/test1
https://example.com/test2
```

With the http**s** added in automatically.

As per this question:
[How to simply make the whole site HTTPS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https)

I've added this at the very end of the D7 .htaccess in the root of the domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is not surrounded by any exceptions.

This seems to enforce SSL, but all pages with http:// get redirected to /index.php

So if I got to:

```
http://example.com/test1
```

I end up at:

```
https://example.com/index.php
```

NOT

```
https://example.com/test1
```

as I'd hoped!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Put that as your _first_ rule, not last

Comment: Genius - that appears to do the trick! Thanks so much! How do I credit you as the correct answer?