# Redirect whole site to HTTPS, with exceptions

Tags: 7, .htaccess, ssl

I've successfully redirected my entire Drupal 7 site to HTTPS using the snippet:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

from [How to simply make the whole site HTTPS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https), but now I want to add an exception for a specific URL (it's an XML feed for products, created with Drupal Commerce + Views Data export). I've tried many variants of this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xmlfeedurl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xmlfeedurl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but haven't managed to get it to work. When I visit `http://www.example.com/xmlfeedurl`, I'm redirected to `https://www.example.com/index.php`.

I'm guessing that there's some interference with Drupal's rule that redirects all URLs to index.php but I have no idea how to solve this (all the above snippets are placed in the detault .htaccess file, just before Drupal's redirect to index.php). Can someone help?