# redirect whole site to HTTPS

Tags: redirection, .htaccess, ssl

When I include the snippet found in answer to this question [How to simply make the whole site HTTPS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https)  to redirect to https in my htaccess.php file, all urls resove to /index instead of going to the page originally requested (Ex: user tries to access example.com/about, and is redirected to https://example.com).

Here is the snippet I used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have also tried the slight variation found at https://www.drupal.org/https-information, which has the same unsatisfactory result:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**How can I make the site all https without breaking the ability to navigate to a specific page?**

Edited to add: I've got the Secure Pages module, but haven't managed to get it to work. If you have advice on that point instead I'd happily take it.

Comment: the file name should be `.htaccess` not `htaccess.php`. This file should be present on the base directory of your drupal where `index.php` exists. ( This only applies for Apache webserver ) and also make sure the mod_rewrite is enabled on your server ( service restart required ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the [htaccess module](https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess):

> Htaccess is a module which autogenerates a Drupal root htaccess file
>   based on your settings.
>
> Drupal tries to provide a one size fits all htaccess for Apache
>   webservers, but this goal is increasingly difficult. This module
>   allows the webmaster to set specific options.
>
> Also, this module is dedicated to webmasters who don't want to
>   manually modify htaccess every time during a version upgrade to use
>   Drupal.

It offers enabling HTTPS and then generates the .htaccess file for you.

Answer (score 11):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this would have worked, but I went with the module since it seemed more likely to be idiot proof :)

Answer (score 0):

The example from @rjkunde didn't work on my local [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando) based drupal development environment, the browser gave me the error message: "The page isn’t redirecting properly". The drupal documentation on [Enabling HTTP Secure (HTTPS)](https://www.drupal.org/https-information#recipes-redirect-all-requests) helped me to solve the problem by adding a second rewrite condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```