# How to configure Secure Pages

Tags: 6, ssl

I'm using Drupal 6 on a website and trying to configure SSL for it.

I installed the [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) module. However I can't figure out the following things:

- How to give secure pages to all anonymous users and admin.
- How to secure all pages of my site in the settings.

The documentation is not extensive.

Please help as I've spent half the day trying to fix this.

Comment: Drupal 6 is EOL since Feb. 2016.

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL certificate at all? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Actually this question could be seen as duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24072. The most upvoted answer does exactly what you want with just a few lines in your `.htaccess`. No additional module needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simply make the whole site use a secure connection?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-do-i-simply-make-the-whole-site-use-a-secure-connection)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, SecurePages has an easy config to enforce HTTPS for everyone on all paths. Check the README.

You could also ditch SecurePages and force all traffic to HTTPS via .htaccess.

Comment: I checked every text file in the tar file of the module and no documentation exists. Secondly I've read the documentation on drupal.org and there is no mention on how to make all pages secure. Also anonymous users are not getting secure pages. Anyone how do I do it via .htaccess? Thanks!

Comment: Anyways, it's a mess... not working at all.

Comment: I vaguely recall that version of the module having issues with that switch. For .htaccess, see something like: https://www.drupal.org/node/336490#comment-1116644

Comment: So I got this and it's working ssl for www.example.com/user how do I modify the htaccess file to allow all pages to be secure? Here is the htaccess on that page, please modify for my purpose. Thanks

Comment: Here is the link https://www.drupal.org/node/336490#comment-2329294

Comment: Is there any way in securepages module for all pages? Documentation is poor :-(