# Forced HTTPS not working on Home Page

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I'm using HTACCESS to force all my pages to redirect to the HTTPS version. However the home page is still able to go to the HTTP version.

I tried 2 examples from this post: [How to simply make the whole site HTTPS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https)

And they work, but not for my home page as I mentioned. HTTPS is redirecting everywhere except the home page.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomainhere\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomainhere.com/ [L,R=301]
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Edit: When I go to the HTTP version of the home page, any time I click a link it redirects to the HTTPS home page instead of the respective link. After that once on the HTTPS home page all links work correctly.

Comment: @leymannx I actually used those two as examples. And they work, except for the home page as I mentioned. My code is under Rewrite engine on.

Comment: I see, I see. Thanks for clarification. Have you tried a different browser, too? Is there something special in the Apache config maybe? Are there any other custom rules added in the `.htaccess`?

Comment: @leymannx So interesting thing... in safari when going to HTTP. Clicking any link redirects to the HTTPS home page instead of the page it should link to. After that all HTTPS links work correctly. Edit: actually this is happening in all browsers.

Comment: Please check my answer below. Also note, that I suggested closing this question as off-topic, as it is merely related to webserver configuration and not to Drupal.

Comment: The first snippet you pasted has a typo on the second line, it should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomainhere\.com$`, notice the `$` at the end instead of `*`.

Comment: And Chrome browser, maybe also the others, caches the redirects. So if you want to be sure if your redirects are working, you should open the developer tools, in developer tool settings disable caching and reload the page without closing the developer tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; $includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>
```

Is what you are looking for. Make sure to place these rules before any other rewriting rules (that may e.g. come from your webserver config).

Comment: Thanks, I put this at the bottom of my HTACCESS after all the drupal stuff and that seemed to do the trick.